# Expanded div-content pushing down other divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to achive something like on that picture:

[Expanded div content -> picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFaeK.jpg)

I got 8 divs (each 25%) floated left (4 in one line)
When I click on button then div content would expand down -> pusshing all divs from secound line. How I could make it? It must be responsive so later on there are 3 divs in one line, and at the end only 1 div in line.

Structure would be something like that:

```
<div class="news-block-wrap">
   <div class="news-block n1">
       <div class="news-block-content"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="news-block n2">
       <div class="news-block-content"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="news-block n3"></div>
   <div class="news-block n4"></div>
   <div class="news-block n5"></div>
   <div class="news-block n6"></div>
   <div class="news-block n7"></div>
   <div class="news-block n8"></div>
</div>
```

I try with position absolute of news-block-content but then its not pushing secound line of divs, I tryied to make it all position relative, but then its destroying all floating "news-block" divs position. Is it possible to do it without Jquery?

Or the only way it is to make news-content absolute position, and add by jquery margin-bottom to news-block to push secound line of divs?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your four buttons then the areas that expand. Something like this.

```
<div class="news-block-wrap">
   <div class="news-block n1"></div>
   <div class="news-block n2"></div>
   <div class="news-block n3"></div>
   <div class="news-block n4"></div>

   <div class="news-block-content" id="n1-area"></div>
   <div class="news-block-content" id="n2-area"></div>
   <div class="news-block-content" id="n3-area"></div>
   <div class="news-block-content" id="n4-area"></div>

   <div class="news-block n5"></div>
   <div class="news-block n6"></div>
   <div class="news-block n7"></div>
   <div class="news-block n8"></div>
</div>
```

This would keep you buttons inline even when one of the news-block-content divs is expanded. You would just need to modify your jQuery to select the correct news block content.

Hope this helps. If you need further explanation comment below.

Comment: That would work if I wont need to make it responsive (later one there are 3 divs on one line, and for mobile there is one div on one line). right?

Comment: I agree this approach would not work that well on mobile. After giving it some thought i'm not sure how to make this design responsive. I would recommend finding a site that uses this system and seeing what they do or make your design more simple to support multiple devices.